# How do i get an image link to change live based on textbox?

Tags: javascript, html, image

i'd like a textbox to change the url of an img

Image Code

```
<img src="http://url.com/ text the user types">
```

All i want to happen is the img url to changed based on a textbox and for it to change live. it has to be appended onto another url like https://google.com/ + text

An example is https://webcode.tools/html-generator/image

Comment: You can apply events on input text to get the value of textbox on keyup .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const textBox = document.getElementById('text-box');
const img = document.getElementById('image');

textBox.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  img.src = `https://google.com/${e.target.value}`
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text-box" placeholder="Enter pic url" />
<img src="" alt="your image" id="image" />
```

there you go